# Anaconda error: failed to create menus when I want to install anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I experience this error:

> failed to create menus when I want to install anaconda.

I have Python 3.7 installed on my laptop although  I remove it  still I get that error. I do not how solve this issue to manage to install anaconda successfully?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://youtu.be/wC8RmgyV0Bc)?